# Webots Attribute Error while getting the robot references

Tags: python, attributeerror, webots

I would like to reproduce the following tutorial, but when I tried to get the robot references theres always this Error:

```
"AttributeError: 'CartpoleRobot' object has no attribute 'getSelf'"
```

I rebuild this Tutorial: https://github.com/aidudezzz/deepbots-tutorials/blob/master/robotSupervisorSchemeTutorial/README.md

In other controllers I get similar error messages when I try to get the robot references. I think the error is in the communication between the robot simulation and the controller.
I have tried importing the supervisor and getting the functions via supervisor.get. But here comes another error: `"Only one instance of the Robot class should be created"`

However, I am new to webots and robotics/informatics in general. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The whole Error with Traceback:

```
INFO: robotSupervisorController: Starting controller: python.exe -u robotSupervisorController.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Webots Projekte\controllers\robotSupervisorController\robotSupervisorController.py", line 88, in <module>
    env = CartpoleRobot()
  File "D:\Webots Projekte\controllers\robotSupervisorController\robotSupervisorController.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.robot = self.getSelf()  # Grab the robot reference from the supervisor to access various robot methods
AttributeError: 'CartpoleRobot' object has no attribute 'getSelf'
WARNING: 'robotSupervisorController' Controller beendet mit Status: 1
```

The Code is the same than shown in the Tutorial.
The short section that generates the error:

```
self.robot = self.getSelf()  # Grab the robot reference from the supervisor to access various robot methods
self.positionSensor = self.getDevice("polePosSensor")
self.positionSensor.enable(self.timestep)
```

If I comment out the first one, the next line returns a similar error

Every answer is highly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I use the deepbots-0.1.2 and webotsR2021a.

Try to uninstall the deepbots and then install them using the:

`pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ deepbots`